# uitableview tags are not working ? Using two tableviews in one uiviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using two tableviews in one view controller, both tables having separate data.

When I implemented the tableview delegate methods, the code is working for only tag1 not for tag2.

I have used almost all possible solution available on StackOverflow but still facing this issue. Here is my code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(tableView.tag==1){
        
        static NSString *myIdentiFier=@"myIdentiFier";
        productCell *cell=(productCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentiFier];
        if(!cell){
            NSArray *cellObjs=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"productCell" owner:self options:nil];
            for(id obj in cellObjs){
                if([obj isKindOfClass:[productCell class]]){
                    cell=(productCell *)obj;
                    break;
                }
            }
            cell.productTitle.text=[nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [cell.productImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rsz_no-image"]];
        }
        
        return cell;
    }
    else{
        static NSString *mileIdentifier=@"mileIdentifier";
        mileStoneTableViewCell *mcell=(mileStoneTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:mileIdentifier];
        if(!mcell){
            NSArray *cellObjs=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"mileStoneTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            for(id obj in cellObjs){
                if([obj isKindOfClass:[mileStoneTableViewCell class]]){
                    mcell=(mileStoneTableViewCell *)obj;
                    break;
                }
            }
            mcell.mile_description.text=[mileStoneDescr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            
        }
        
        return mcell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set datasource and delegate for 2nd table ? Check it once.

Comment: are you set tag = 2 for second table as well ?

Comment: i have set tag=1 for my first tableview and tag=2 for second tableview.

Comment: Else part is not working or not even enter into else part ?

Comment: its going into else part after i am running app for second time.

Comment: where do you set tag ? view did load or in XIB ?

Comment: i have tried for both ..in xib and in .m but not working for anyone.

Comment: hey you are not returning cell in second condition

Comment: return cell; mention it in the else condition also this is the issue

Comment: Purva according to me no issue regarding return cell..return cell call in seprate condition, I have doubt in only set TAG for both table..@dipak i want to know correctly where are you set TAG for table?

Comment: purva i am returning cell in else condition..i have to return it either it will not return any cell in my second tableview.

Comment: have you implemented same condition in - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section method???

Comment: @DipenChudasama my tags are set into XIB

Comment: @Deepak: tell me when you switch from one tableview(tag=1) to another(tag=2).?

Comment: @NiravPatel i am switching tableview tag=2 after fetching data for one tableview (tag=1) completely after that it'll go for else part.

Comment: can you post that code??? i am not getting you.... i think you are not reloading tableview of tag=2,after you have fetched data from tableview of tag=1.

Comment: for cellForRowAtIndexPath you can see in my question and other delegate methods are following.


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    
    if(tableView==self.productTable)
    {
    NSLog(@"%d",[productImageArray count]);
    return [productImageArray count];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",[mileStoneDescr count]);
        return[mileStoneDescr count];
    }
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 70;
}

Comment: but where you have written tableview reload method? like [tableview(tag=2) reloaddata];?

Comment: @NiravPatel in viewDidLoad

Comment: @Deepak: let me tell you that you will not get else part in cellForRowAtIndexPath until you reload your second tableview(tag = 2).According to your code you are reloading tableview(tag =1) in viewdidLoad method.so how can it will go in else part my friend? you will have to call [secondtableview reloaddata] somewhere , then only it will go in else part.

Comment: @NiravPatel ok got it but somewhere ??

Comment: @Deepak: i don't know man...it depends upon on your application flow...if you reload your secondtableview(tag=2) in viewdidload ,then directly it will go to else part.You can reload your second tableview in some button action my friend

Comment: @NiravPatel ok bro.. lemme try this..i'll get back to you after try this.

Comment: hmmm. i hope i wll get some benifit....

Comment: yeah i got it .. i am trying your solution

Comment: and also don't use if(tableView==self.productTable) in numberOfRowsInSection method , instead use if(tableView.tag==1)...

Comment: @NiravPatel tried both your solutions still not working

Comment: what you have written,can you please tell me?

Comment: i have put reloaddata in a button. after click it will reload data untill data will remain r=same in both table

Comment: I am not getting you my friend...Now what you can do is give me dropbox link of your those files.and i can figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

keep a reference to each of the table views

//viewcontroller.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* firstTableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* secondTableView;
```

In the datasource/ delegate methods you need to account for the fact that the method needs to behave differently depending on which table view is in use. e.g.

//viewcontroller.m

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    if (tableView == self.firstTableView) {

        ...

    } else { // tableView == self.secondTableView

        ...
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: have you connected outlets of both table view in xib?

Comment: is it not going in condition? have you mention this condition in numberofRos in section?

Comment: What tag set for both table ?

Comment: Actually both tableview are not fetching data in same time..both are fetching data in consecutively .one tableview fetching data on first run , and another one fetching data on second run of app.

Comment: ok set tag 1 for tableview1 and set tag 2 for tableview 2 in xib  then instead of  if (tableView == self.firstTableView) you have to check condiltion like  if (tableView.tag == 1){} else if  if (tableView.tag == 2) {

Comment: Purva i have tried already and i have also tried after your suggestion..still issue is in the  air ..not working..

Comment: @deepak I think your code is Terminating after return cell;

please Put it in else block

NSLog(@"Code is not breaking");

Answer (score 0):

Please note the following:
 1. Have you called `[self.secondTableView reloadData]`.
 2. Try `NSLog(@"%d", self.secondTableView.tag)` to make sure that the tag is set correctly.
 3. Have you used interface builder to set the tag or did you set it programatically? If you have set it programatically, make sure you have set the tag before you call `reloadData`.
 4. Finally make sure your `dataSource` and `delegate` is set correctly.
 5. If you have two tableViews, it is advisable not to set the `dataSource` and `Delegate` of both the tableViews by control dragging in Interface Builder. In some cases that may cause the app to crash. Set either one or both of the tableView's `datasource` and `delegate` programatically.

If all this is correct you code should work.